# How to split PDF file at a given keyword using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, split, keyword

I'd like to be able to parse a PDF file using PHP, specifically search the large PDF file using certain keywords and split it into multiple PDF files at the keywords searched for.

I did some research and I found a lot of ways to write PDF files using PHP but very few to parse and split the PDF file.

any web-sites I could go to? libraries I could use?

Comment: I'm curious. Why use PHP for this task?

Comment: PHP's code is very flexible which speeds up the development process and that was one of the main requirements for the project (Rails is a better option for big projects).